# Upload artifacts to s3 from Jenkins

Tags: amazon-s3, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am using **Jenkins**, on Post Build i want to push artifacts to S3.
but i am getting the following error :

```
Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId; Request ID: E9EF9BE1E1D0C011), S3 Extended Request ID: wsyJXgV9If7Yk/GbgI486HrQ5RFZbvnQt/haOBJq3nZ6aLFbWEvKmnHE9ly+05eOab2qTPOQjZU=
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1275)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:873)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:576)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:362)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:328)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:307)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3659)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.initiateMultipartUpload(AmazonS3Client.java:2651)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.initiateMultipartUpload(UploadCallable.java:350)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.uploadInParts(UploadCallable.java:178)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.call(UploadCallable.java:121)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:139)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:47)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried with Java 1.8 latest , java 1.7 latest. But getting this error again and again. I tried **s3 publish plugin** 0.8 and also 0.10.1.

**Project Config :**
[image: Project Config]

**Plugin Config :**
[image: plugin Config]

Comment: InvalidAccessKeyId: Are you using correct credentials?

Comment: I am facing exactly same problem. Any Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a 403 (forbidden) error, which indicates that you're either missing valid credentials for the bucket, or that the bucket's security settings, such as server-side encryption (SSE), are not being respected.

**First**, update to the latest version of the S3 publisher plugin - it's added support for SSE, and if your bucket needs it enabled, you can check the box for "Server side encryption" in your pipeline configuration.

**Second**, you'll need to modify the S3 profile in the Jenkins "Configure System" form.  In your question, the highlighted field for your access key is empty, and that *must* be provided, along with the secret key component.

Once you've entered the configuration correctly and verified that bucket requirements are satisfied, you should be in the clear for pushing your objects to S3.

Answer (score -2):

I had same issue while I tried to push artifacts to an S3 bucket by a Jenkins. Later I found out that it threw errors because I was providing a wrong Bucket in the Jenkins config.